# Not Able to receive push notification in my Blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am currently testing push service on the devel system and the response code of pushed messages to the system is:

Our PUSH-ID: xxxxxxx
   PUSH-ID: xxxxxxxx
   REPLY-TIME: 2013-12-14T17:20:16Z
   Response CODE: 1001
   Response DESC: The request has been accepted for processing.
﻿
What does it mean? They accepted the message, but they are not pushing the message to the devices? I would think I need to get a "200" for a successful push to the devices. Or I am wrong?

Comment: BIS is activated on your Device ?.

Comment: Yes its showing active.

Comment: i have same problem. can anybody help me

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Everything is proper, still device is not receiving push, do I need to enable any port for this?